# Como eu posso recuperar o valor de uma variavel enviado por data-myVar e utilizar no checkbox?

Tags: php, html, laravel

```
index.blade.php
<table>
    @foreach($masters as $master)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$master->receive_email_neworder_masters}}</td>
            <td>
                <button
                    class="btn btn-info"
                    data-my_table = "masters"
                    data-myVar = "{{$master->receive_email_neworder_masters}}"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#edit">Edit
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="box box-primary box-header with-border">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit </h4>
                </div>
                <form action="{{route('masters.update', 'test')}}" method="post">
                    {{method_field('patch')}}
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        @include('masters.form_edit')
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); {
    var myVar = button.data('myVar');
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-body #strVar').val(myVar);
    }
}
</script>

form.blade.php    
<div class="input-group">
    <input name="checkbox"
        id="idvar"
        type="checkbox"
        checked="strVar"> <!-- Quero usar aqui -->
    <label>
        I will desire receive email when insert new order.
    </label>
    <br />
</div>
```

Dentro do checkbox quero fazer o checked conforme o valor de myVar (Yes or No), o valor que está no campo e já confirmado via alert(strVar) está setado para No mas está funcionando dentro do checkbox. O foreach faz uma lista e para cada registro eu seto uma variavel e coloco dentro do botão, depois no script eu pego o valor e seto para uma variavel que será usada dentro de uma modal com um form. Tudo funciona bem para outros fins, mas dentro do checkbox eu não consigo fazer funcionar e não sei acessar a variavel.

De forma simplificada, seria algo para funcionar assim:

```
'id_buildings é uma variavel setada dentro do script e funciona bem aqui no input'
<label>Buindings</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_buildings" readonly="readonly" id="id_buildings">

<script>
    $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var id_buildings = button.data('my_id_buildings');
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-body #id_buildings').val(id_buildings);
        modal.find('  ').val(id_buildings);
    }
</script>

'id_building não funciona aqui porque ela não é um tipo php'
{!! Form::select('id_buildings', $buildings, null ) !!
```

Obrigado pessoal por qualquer tipo de ajuda!

Comment: Tenta explicar melhor tua duvida, tenha em mente que não sabemos como é sua interface, ou qualquer outra coisa.

Comment: Sim, vou alterar a pergunta! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Simples, não sei se é o melhor modo, mas é o mais rapido, cria uma $_SESSION[] joga o valor dentro recupera onde você quer e destrói a sessão

Atualizando
Com o valor já recuperado dentro da sessao você vai fazer o seguinte.
vamos supor que você criou a sessao valor ex
$_SESSION['valor'];
no chekbox vc vai fazer isso

inesplicavel como eu não consigo colocar os codigos aqui nesse stack em portugues é impressionante, mas faz o seguinte colei o codigo no pastebin

https://pastebin.com/3NtUpYiJ

Comment: Se eu for usar esse recurso como o ultimo recurso, voce poderia me dizer como ficaria dentro do checkbox? Um exemplo simples? Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, fiz um exemplo na pratica pra vc, só vc implementar no seu codigo

Comment: Obrigado novamente, copiei o codigo, vou testar.

Comment: tranquilo, depois de testar comenta aqui se funcionou.

Comment: Entao... @Martins Luan a proposta é recuperar o valor da variavel com os valores do button e através do javascript repassar ao checkbox, não tenho acesso a variável via PHP, portanto não tem como aplicar dessa forma como você mencionou. Obrigado por enquanto.